# Phone application and no landscape on nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I bought a nexus 7 because I was intensely curious about Ubuntu for tablets. However, I can only surmise that I chose the wrong channel or something because not only does it have a phone app, it also has no landscape other than in the web browser. Either that, or that's just how it is for the nexus 7 (2013 wifi)

I chose the rtm proposed channel recommended by some Ubuntu website with a chart of what device you have and what channel to choose. I'm unsure of the full name but in OS build details it calls it Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn (development branch) - armhf.

To reiterate: Should I have chosen a different build to get a non-phone gui or did I choose the right one and that's just how it is supposed to be?